# Can Perl print an image using CSS into a PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am printing a PDF using Open2 in Perl it takes the HTML template and prints it out to a PDF that can be downloaded via a button.

They wanted a watermark on it, so I used

```
<style>
   body {
      background-image: url("watermark.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
</style>
```

on the preview page it looks great, but when you download it to the PDF it disappears. Any way I can add this to my PDF?

PDF Code Generator Below

```
sub pdfGenerator {
my $data = shift;
my $file = "$OUTFILES/$data.html";

open(my $fileFH, '<', $file) or return "Can not find file\n";   

my $processId = open2(\*POUT, \*PIN, qq(html2ps -U -f /home/dir/cgi-bin/dir2/html2psrc-label));

my @lines = <$fileFH>;
print PIN @lines;
close PIN;

my @psLines;
while (<POUT>) 
{
    chomp;
    push(@psLines,$_);
}
waitpid $processId, 0;

$processId = open2(\*POUT, \*PIN, qq(ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter - -));
print PIN "$_\n" foreach(@psLines);
close PIN;

my @pdfLines;
while (<POUT>) {
    chomp;
    push(@pdfLines, $_);
}
waitpid $processId, 0;

  print "Content-Type: application/pdf\n";
  print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pdfName.pdf\n\n";
  print "$_\n" foreach(@pdfLines);
```

}

I have tried altering the html2ps file and I am still not getting anything.
my code is below

```
 @html2ps
{
   paper
   {
      type: letter;
   }
}

BODY
{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin: 2em 1em 2em 70px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;
    background-image: url("/dir/images/watermark.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@page
{
   margin-left:   .75in;
   margin-right:  .75in;
   margin-top:    1in;
   margin-bottom: 1in;
}
```

Comment: If you generate the PDF from the command line using `html2ps`, does it show the watermark? Is the path to the watermark accessible and known to `html2ps`?

Comment: This is not a Perl question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> html2ps ignores css contained in the html document. You can define
>   styles in the configuration file. Only a subset of css is supported by
>   html2ps.

So you need to put it in conf file.

See this example: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2008/ED-xml-events-20080624/html2ps.conf

In the example you can notice usage of `background-image` for `BODY` tag.